# Puxar resultados de duas tabelas MySQL com classe PHP

Tags: php, mysql, html5

Criei uma classe para a geração dinâmica de tabelas com resultados vindos do MySQL. A sintaxe que eu utilizo após instanciar a classe é a seguinte:

```
$table->topo('Menu:','menu','menu');
$table->Corpo('menu_sub','ID,Nome,Menu,Icones','id,nome,id_menu,icone','','','','id_menu,icone','menu','id','nome,nome');
```

Os últimos campos são referentes a uma consulta em uma segunda tabela do MySQL

[image: Listagem mysql]

O campo nome funciona perfeitamente porem como podem observar o campo marcado em vermelho o mesmo esta puxando os outros campos da tabela principal, resolvi isso modificando esta parte do código

```
if ($v == $z) {
    echo 'Acho ->'.$z;
}else{
    echo 'p';   //MUDEI ESTA PARTE AQUI DO CODIGO
}

}
```

Bem agora que vem o meu maior problema quero fazer consulta em mais de uma tabela.

Eu imaginei que resolveria separando os campos por `(Tipo: id_menu,icone)` o que ocorre eu mostro na imagem a seguir

[image: Resultado em select em mais de uma tabela]

```
$table->topo('Menu:','menu','menu');
$table->Corpo('menu_sub','ID,Nome,Menu,Icones','id,nome,id_menu,icone','','','','id_menu,icone','menuicones','id,icone','menu,icone');
```

Resumindo com apenas um único campo eu consigo puxar os resultados da segunda tabela porem se eu tentar puxar o resultado de mais de uma tabela ai tenho o problema mostrado na imagem acima, tenho resultado duplicado.

[image: Exemplo de como funciona a chamada da classe]

Segue a classe responsável pela criação da tabela dinâmica:

PS. Esta classe esta sem os SQL responsável pelo `select` em segunda tabela

```
<?php
class Tabela{
    /*
     * TOPO BARRA DE NAVEGAÇÃO DA TABELA MASTER
     */
    function topo($nome,$modulo,$arquivo){
        echo '
        <div style="padding:0 10px;"><div  style="border-bottom: solid 3px #297ACC">
        <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
            <tr>
                <td width="92%"><strong>'.$nome.'</strong></td>
                <td width="8%" align="right"><ul class="nav  span7" style="margin-bottom:0px;">
                        <li class="pull-right"><a href="?pg=modulos/'.$modulo.'/list_'.$arquivo.'">Listar</a></li>
                        <li class="pull-right"><a href="?pg=modulos/'.$modulo.'/add_'.$arquivo.'">Cadastrar</a></li>
                    </ul></td>
            </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
        <br />
            ';
    }
    /*
     * GERADOR AUTOMATICO DE TABELA
     * ESTA FUNÇÃO IRA GERA UMA SQL ONDE OS DADOS VIRÃO DINAMICAMENTE
     */
    function Corpo($db,$th,$campos,$where,$modulos,$files,$_campo,$_tb,$_where,$_valor){
        $pag = "$_GET[pag]";
        if($pag >=  '1'){
            $pag = $pag;
        }else{
            $pag = '1';
        }
        $maximo = '10';
        $inicio = ($pag * $maximo) - $maximo;
        $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $db $where LIMIT $inicio, $maximo");
        /*
         * AQUI FICA O CABEÇALHO DA TABELA
         */
        echo
        '<table border="1" width="100%" >
            <tr>
            ';
        $v = explode(',',$th);;
        foreach($v as $x){
            echo '<th>'.ucfirst($x).'</th>';   
        }
        /*
         * AQUI VAI O LOOP DA TABELA
         */
        echo '
                <th colspan="2">Ações</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>';
        while($dados = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){   
            foreach(explode(',',$campos) as $v) {   
                $x = $dados[$v];
                $d = explode(',', $_campo);
                echo '<td>';
            foreach ($d as $z) {
                    if ($v == $z) {
                        echo 'Acho ->'.$z;
                        }else{
                        }
                    }
                echo 'p';
                echo '</td>';
                }

            echo '
                <td width="1"><a href="?pg=modulos/'.$modulos.'/edit_'.$files.'&id='.$dados[id].'" class="fa fa-edit"></a></td>
                <td width="1"><a href="?pg=modulos/'.$modulos.'/dell_'.$files.'&id='.$dados[id].'" class="fa fa-close" style="color:#FF0000;"></a> </td>
            </tr>';
        }
        echo '
        </table>';

        /*
         * PAGINAÇÃO COM NUMERAÇÃO
         */
        echo '<ul class="pagination">';
        $sql_res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $db $where");
        $total = mysql_num_rows($sql_res);
        $paginas = ceil($total/$maximo);
        $links = '5';
        echo "<li><a href=\"?pg=modulos/$modulos/list_$files&pag=1\">«</a></li>";
        for ($i = $pag-$links; $i <= $pag-1; $i++){
            if($i >= 0){
                echo "<li><a href=\"?pg=modulos/$modulos/list_$files&pag=$i\">$i</a></li>";
            }
        }

        echo '<li class="disabled"><a href="#">'.$pag.'</a></li>';
        for($i = $pag +1; $i <= $pag+$links; $i++){
            if($i > $paginas){
            }  else {
                echo "<li><a href=\"?pg=modulos/$modulos/list_$files&pag=$i\">$i</a></li>";
            }
        }

        echo "<li><a href=\"?pg=modulos/$modulos/list_$files&pag=$paginas\">»</a></li>";    
    }
}
```

Aqui eu deixo o [link para o projeto](https://github.com/AlexandreSousa/framwork) que coloquei no GIT.

Comment: O primeiro trecho de código tem uma `}` sobrando. Não tirei porque editores só devem formatar código e não alterá-lo. Alexandre, porque tem a tag HTML5? E não MySQL?

Comment: Este código e uma referencia a parte que tem na classe, porem a ideia e a classe gera uma tabela em html

Comment: Que confusão, não percebi nada. Qual o problema? É o tamanho das colunas da tabela? Ou é o carregar os valores errados?

Comment: Carregar valores errados, baixe o código no git e da uma olhada que você vai entender

Answer (score 1):

Vamos focar no seu código principal, que gera o loop da tabela.

## Erro de tag

Logo no começo, você imprime um `<tr>`. Porém está antes do `while`, então vai faltar a tag para as próximas linhas.

Isso:

```php
echo '
        <th colspan="2">Ações</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>';
while($dados = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){   
    ...
```

Deveria ser:

```php
//finaliza o cabeçalho
echo '
        <th colspan="2">Ações</th>
    </tr>'; 
while($dados = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){   
    //define o início de cada linha
    echo '<tr>'; 
    ....
```

## Recuperando campos de várias tabelas

Fora isso, não deveria haver distinção alguma para você recuperar ("puxar") dados de diferentes tabelas. Quando você seleciona campos num comando `SELECT`, o registro retornado não diferencia por tabela.

O que quero dizer é que não importa a qual tabela o campo pertence, desde que esteja no `SELECT`.

Veja os exemplos a seguir:

```sql
select tab1.campo1, tab1.campo2, tab1.campo3 from tab1, tab 2 where ...

select tab1.campo1, tab1.campo2, tab1.campo3 from tab1 where ...

select tab1.campo1, tab1.campo2, tab3.campo3 from tab1, tab2, tab3 where ...
```

Independe de como é a query, o array retornado será exatamente o mesmo, contendo as chaves `campo1`, `campo2` e `campo3`.

Logo, para imprimir todas os valores da tabela, basta imprimir o valor de `$x`, onde você já recuperou os valores.

Finalmente, o laço ficaria poderia ser simplesmente assim:

```
while($dados = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){   
    echo '<tr>';
    foreach(explode(',',$campos) as $v) {   
        $x = $dados[$v];
        echo '<td>'.$x.'</td>';
    }
    echo '
        <td width="1"><a href="?pg=modulos/'.$modulos.'/edit_'.$files.'&id='.$dados[id].'" class="fa fa-edit"></a></td>
        <td width="1"><a href="?pg=modulos/'.$modulos.'/dell_'.$files.'&id='.$dados[id].'" class="fa fa-close" style="color:#FF0000;"></a> </td>
    </tr>';
}
```

Caso você queira fazer algum tratamento diferenciado para o caso do campo de ser outra tabela, aí você pode usar o vetor `$d` e verificar de `$v` está contido nele.